# Read bootsector redux

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, boot

Okay, my turn to ask a question. "What's wrong with my code?" It is a dos .com file (x86), written in Nasm, and run under a boot to FreeDos (not DosBox).

```
; nasm -f bin -o readmbr.com readmbr.asm

org 100h ; offset where dos will load us

section .text

mov si, 5 ; retry count
read:
mov dx, 80h ; drive
mov cx, 1 ; segment
mov bx, buffer
mov ax, 201h ; read 1 sector
int 13h
jnc goodread

mov ah, 0 ; reset drive
int 13h
dec si
jnz read
jmp exit

goodread:
mov si, buffer
mov cx, 512
top:
lodsb
aam 16
xchg al, ah
call printhex
xchg al, ah
call printhex
mov al, ' '
int 29h
loop top

exit:
int 20h
;mov ah, 4Ch
;int 21h
; ret
printhex:
cmp al, 9
jbe not_alpha
add al, 7
not_alpha:
add al, '0'
int 29h ; print the character in al
ret

section .bss
buffer resb 512
```

When I step through this in a debugger (FreeDos' DEBUG), I get the expected output (more or less), but instead of "program terminated normally", I get "unexpected single-step breakpoint" (or similar), and the `ip` indicates I'm "off in the woods". When I try to run it "at speed", it hangs the machine with no output at all! Dos boots pretty quickly these days, but it still gets old after a while. I think it's time to put some other eyes on this!

I realize I've done some "less well documented" things - `aam 16` and `int 29h` for example - but these things "used to work" for me... and seem to work in the debugger. What am I doing that makes the machine hang (with no output at all)?

Amit, if you're so inclined, tell me what this does in DosBox. Anyone else, thanks for any help!

Edit: Okay... I "fixed" it. I don't know how! With the "completely meaningless interrupt", it works. Without it, same result as before - hangs with no output. Apparently, FreeDos doesn't like `int 13h` as the first interrupt(?). No idea why. I don't recall ever seeing anything like this before. This version has a slightly nicer hexdump - includes ascii too, which should make it easier to tell if you're looking at a real bootsector or not. I have an idea it isn't going to work in DosBox... which makes the whole exercise rather pointless...

```
; nasm f-bin -o readmbr.com readmbr.asm

org 100h

section .bss
    buffer resb 512

section .text

; completely meaningless interrupt!
    mov dl, 13
    mov ah, 2
    int 21h

    mov dx, 80h ; drive
    mov cx, 1 ; sector (not "segment", idiot)
    mov bx, buffer
    mov ax, 201h ; read one sector
    int 13h
    jc exit

; dump 512 bytes as hex, and ascii (if printable), 16 at a time
    mov si, buffer
    mov di, 32 ; loop counter
dumpem:
    call dump16
    dec di
    jnz dumpem

exit:
    ret
;------------------

;--------------------
; print character in al to stdout
; returns: nothing useful
printchar:
    push ax
    push dx
    mov dl, al
    mov ah, 2
    int 21h
    pop dx
    pop ax
    ret
;------------------

;--------------------
dump16:
; prints 16 bytes pointed to by si, as hex and as ascii (if printable)
; returns: si pointed to next byte. ax, cx trashed.

    mov cx, 16
    push si ; save it for the ascii part
top:
    lodsb ; al <- [si], inc si
    aam 16 ; split al into ah and al - four bits per
    xchg al, ah ; we want the high one first
    cmp al, 9
    jbe not_alpha
    add al, 7 ; bump 10 - 15 up to 'A' - 'F'
not_alpha:
    add al, '0'
    call printchar
    xchg al, ah ; swap 'em back and print low nibble
    cmp al, 9
    jbe not_alpha2
    add al, 7
not_alpha2:
    add al, '0'
    call printchar
    mov al, ' '
    call printchar
    loop top

    mov al, '|'
    call printchar
    mov al, ' '
    call printchar

    pop si ; get back pointer to 16 bytes
    mov cx, 16
asciitop:
    lodsb
    cmp al, 20h ; we don't want to print control characters!
    jae printable
    mov al, '.'
printable:
    call printchar
    loop asciitop
; and throw a CR/LF
    mov al, 13
    call printchar
    mov al, 10
    call printchar
    ret
;--------------------
```

Want the Linux version, while we're at it? Why not? Might be more useful...

```
; nasm -f elf32 myprog.asm
; ld -o myprog myprog.o -melf_i386
;
; since only root is going to have access to the MBR,
; run it as root... or if you wish a user to be able to run it...
; as root:
; chown root:root myprog
; chmod +s myprog

global _start

section .data

; on my valuable antique system, this is the first hard drive
; (not necessarily the one I booted from)
; on a more modern system, probably "sda" or so...?

    filename db "/dev/hda", 0

section .bss
    buffer resb 512
    file_desc resd 1

section .text
_start:
    nop

; open the file
    ; don't care about edx, since we're not creating the file
    mov ecx, 0 ; readonly
    mov ebx, filename
    mov eax, 5 ; sys_open
    int 80h

    test eax, eax ; fancy error handler :)
    js exit
    mov [file_desc], eax

; read all 512 bytes
    mov edx, 512
    mov ecx, buffer
    mov ebx, [file_desc]
    mov eax, 3 ; sys_read
    int 80h
    test eax, eax
    js exit

; dump 512 bytes as hex, and ascii (if printable), 16 at a time
    mov esi, buffer
    mov edi, 32
dumpem:
    call dump16
    dec edi
    jnz dumpem

; the exit would close the file, but we'll be nice and close it
    mov ebx, [file_desc]
    mov eax, 6 ; sys_close
    int 80h
    test eax, eax
    js exit

; if we get here, pretend there was no error

    xor eax, eax

exit:

; if there was an error, return it as an exit-code,
; negated for easy readability.
; view it with "echo $?".

    mov ebx, eax
    neg ebx
    mov eax, 1 ; sys_exit
    int 80h
;------------------

;--------------------
; print character in al to stdout
; returns: nothing useful
printchar:
    push edx ; save these, by preference
    push ecx
    push ebx ; C would expect ebx to be preserved
    push eax ; has to be last - it serves as our buffer

    mov ecx, esp ; buffer's on the stack
    mov edx, 1 ; one only please
    mov ebx, 1 ; stdout
    mov eax, 4 ; sys_write
    int 80h

    pop eax
    pop ebx
    pop ecx
    pop edx
    ret
;------------------

;--------------------
dump16:
; prints 16 bytes pointed to by esi, as hex and as ascii (if printable)
; returns: esi pointed to next byte. eax, ecx trashed.

    mov ecx, 16
    push esi ; save it for the ascii part
top:
    lodsb ; al <- [esi], inc esi
    aam 16 ; split al into ah and al - four bits per
    xchg al, ah ; we want the high one first
    cmp al, 9
    jbe not_alpha
    add al, 7 ; bump 10 - 15 up to 'A' - 'F'
not_alpha:
    add al, '0'
    call printchar
    xchg al, ah ; swap 'em back and print low nibble
    cmp al, 9
    jbe not_alpha2
    add al, 7
 not_alpha2:
    add al, '0'
    call printchar
    mov al, ' '
    call printchar
    loop top

    mov al, '|'
    call printchar
    mov al, ' '
    call printchar

    pop esi ; get back pointer to 16 bytes
    mov ecx, 16
asciitop:
    lodsb
    cmp al, 20h ; we don't want to print control characters!
    jae printable
    mov al, '.'
printable:
    call printchar
    loop asciitop
; and throw a linefeed...
    mov al, 10
    call printchar
    ret
;--------------------
```

... and that's enough for now...

Comment: _"tell me what this does in DosBox"_: It prints a screenful of 00s.

Comment: @Frank I don't have access to my DosBox now,Once I have it ,will  let you know.

Comment: @Frank just found this link which uses aam16 to print in hex but not sure is it of any use for you.http://www.programmersheaven.com/mb/x86_asm/206762/206762/aam-16-discovered-4-hex-prints/?S=900000

Comment: Hi Frank when I run this program in my Dosbox ,I can see hexdump , I mean Hex values,but how can I make sure that its my HARD disk bootsector,would I have to check last 2 bytes which contains signature values,will be attaching the screen-shot of my Dosbox in answer

Comment: @Frank I tried to decode these hex values to ascii and looks like,its printing the code you have given ,is it what is expected here??

Comment: @Frank First time on SO saw a question itself is having all the answer,I really wanted to appreciate the effort you have put  in for this problem,Now I don't mind  whether it work on DosBox or not ,Personally I learnt quite a lot from this discussion and would like say word Thanks to you!!

Comment: I found dosbox insufficient for most tasks (other than running small .com programs in DEBUG.COM or somesuch) and suggest qemu instead (bonus: attach gdb; my [.gdbinit](https://www.mirbsd.org/cvs.cgi/contrib/hosted/tg/.gdbinit?rev=HEAD) helps with that). Also, I wrote a Conway's Game of Life in GWBASIC, optimised it in asm, and it *still* was slow in dosbox – turns out it hardcodes a 20 MHz or so CPU, Qemu runs at speed.

Answer (score 1):

Okay. This is the output from the Linux version (easier than rebooting). It "wraps" horribly, but you can see that it's "LILO".

```
FA EB 21 01 B2 01 4C 49 4C 4F 16 07 80 60 FC 47 | úë!.².LILO..`üG
00 00 00 00 FA 9A FA 47 40 F6 3F 30 81 00 80 60 | ....úúG@ö?0.`
16 2B F3 01 B8 C0 07 8E D0 BC 00 08 FB 52 53 06 | .+ó.¸À.Ð¼..ûRS.
56 FC 8E D8 31 ED 60 B8 00 12 B3 36 CD 10 61 B0 | VüØ1í`¸..³6Í.a°
0D E8 64 01 B0 0A E8 5F 01 B0 4C E8 5A 01 60 1E | .èd.°.è_.°LèZ.`.
07 80 FA FE 75 02 88 F2 BB 00 02 8A 76 1E 89 D0 | .úþu.ò»..v.Ð
80 E4 80 30 E0 78 0A 3C 10 73 06 F6 46 1C 40 75 | ä0àx.<.s.öF.@u
2E 88 F2 66 8B 76 18 66 09 F6 74 23 52 B4 08 B2 | .òfv.f.öt#R´.²
80 53 CD 13 5B 72 57 0F B6 CA BA 7F 00 42 66 31 | SÍ.[rW.¶Êº.Bf1
C0 40 E8 60 00 66 3B B7 B8 01 74 03 E2 EF 5A 53 | À@è`.f;·¸.t.âïZS
8A 76 1F BE 20 00 E8 DD 00 B4 99 66 81 7F FC 4C | v.¾ .èÝ.´füL
49 4C 4F 75 29 5E 68 80 08 07 31 DB E8 C7 00 75 | ILOu)^h..1ÛèÇ.u
FB BE 06 00 89 F7 B9 0A 00 B4 9A F3 A6 75 0F B0 | û¾..÷¹..´ó¦u.°
02 AE 75 0A 06 55 B0 49 E8 CD 00 CB B4 40 B0 20 | .®u..U°IèÍ.Ë´@° 
E8 C5 00 E8 B2 00 FE 4E 00 74 07 BC E8 07 61 E9 | èÅ.è².þN.t.¼è.aé
5C FF F4 EB FD 60 55 55 66 50 06 53 6A 01 6A 10 | \ÿôëý`UUfP.Sj.j.
89 E6 53 F6 C6 60 74 6E F6 C6 20 74 14 BB AA 55 | æSöÆ`tnöÆ t.»ªU
B4 41 CD 13 72 0B 81 FB 55 AA 75 05 F6 C1 01 75 | ´AÍ.r.ûUªu.öÁ.u
3F 52 06 B4 08 CD 13 07 72 B4 51 C0 E9 06 86 E9 | ?R.´.Í..r´QÀé.é
89 CF 59 C1 EA 08 92 40 83 E1 3F F7 E1 93 8B 44 | ÏYÁê.@á?÷áD
08 8B 54 0A 39 DA 73 94 F7 F3 39 F8 77 8E C0 E4 | .T.9Ús÷ó9øwÀä
06 86 E0 92 F6 F1 08 E2 89 D1 41 5A 88 C6 EB 1C | .àöñ.âÑAZÆë.
B4 42 5B BD 05 00 60 CD 13 73 16 4D 74 BA 31 C0 | ´B[½..`Í.s.Mtº1À
CD 13 61 4D EB F0 66 50 59 58 88 E6 B8 01 02 EB | Í.aMëðfPYXæ¸..ë
E1 8D 64 10 61 C3 66 AD 66 09 C0 74 0A 66 03 46 | ád.aÃf­f.Àt.f.F
10 E8 61 FF 80 C7 02 C3 C1 C0 04 E8 03 00 C1 C0 | .èaÿÇ.ÃÁÀ.è..ÁÀ
04 24 0F 27 04 F0 14 40 60 BB 07 00 B4 0E CD 10 | .$.'.ð.@`»..´.Í.
61 C3 00 00 00 00 44 63 40 F6 3F 30 73 20 80 01 | aÃ....Dc@ö?0s .
01 00 83 EF FF FF 3F 00 00 00 41 45 31 09 00 EF | ..ïÿÿ?...AE1..ï
FF FF 82 EF FF FF 80 45 31 09 D0 87 20 00 00 00 | ÿÿïÿÿE1.Ð ...
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 | ................
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 55 AA | ..............Uª
```

Comment: Thanks Frank ,Looks like I am out of luck here because I could see only black screen when runs the Linux version of code

Comment: @AmitSinghTomar Okay, the Linux version, if you type `echo $?` immediately after running it, should print an error number. 13 is the most common one I get - permission denied. Means I forgot to run it as root, or "cook" the file as described in the comments. 2 - no such file, 6 - no such device or address, 19 - no such device. Look 'em up in errno.h if you have to. If it says 0, my code's just buggy. I think the easest way to tell what device you booted from is type `df` and see what's mounted on "/". Courage! fbkotler@myfairpoint.net

Comment: HI Frank I did what you suggested ,echo $? ,output of which comes out to be 2 means no such file and output of df shows /dev/loop0 is mounted on "/".What should I make of it ,/dev/loop0 doesn't looks like its booted from hard drive or does it??

Comment: I don't know what to make of /dev/loop0. Sounds like a "virtual boot"? Do you get any output if you make that the `filename`?

Comment: Thank you so much frank.Finally I guess I am able to see boot sector of hard drive ,I changed the filename to /dev/sda3 which is mounted on /host,changing filename to /dev/loop0 gives me full of 0's.I have attached output of linux version of code with filname /dev/sda3.Would you like to confirm it.I also would like to know what next exercise or next thing I can do to learn more about real mode coding in x86 ,though read the bootsector  in protected mode.It would be great help If you let me know how to process further in learning real mode stuff.

Comment: Yes, that looks like an MBR! Congratulations! The "NTFS" suggests that it is/was originally a Windows drive. That may explain "/host" and "/loop0", which I've never seen before. I'm feeling a lot like a "clueless newbie" myself, these days! I don't know what to suggest next for real mode coding/learning. Maybe find and print out environment variables? A "new question" may be in order - this one's getting pretty old...

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Find the attached output of your code run in a dosbox environment. One interesting point I want to raise  here, when I replace the int29h to int 10h/ah=0x0e , output is different the hex values have changed.

[image]

Comment: Like an idiot, I neglected to put "assembly" in my "tags". Thanks for fixing that, whoever did it. I'm new here, what can i say? Neither all zeros, nor your posted screen-shot looks like a bootsector. "DosBox", being virtual, may not see the "real" hard drive. (serious security violation if you can write to the real hard drive!) I'll reboot to FreeDos and try it again, not trying to be so "clever" this time. :) Easier for me to write a Linux program - completely different method. I'll get back to you. Thanks to all for the feedback so far!

Comment: @FrankKotler is it possible for you to attach the O/P of you MBR here